# THREE.JSONLoader Error in Chrome

Tags: javascript, webgl

I converted a model. Obj to. Js

When I try to load the. Js with THREE.JSONLoader like this:

```js
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( {model: "/modelos/modelos3D/Dragon.js", callback: agregarDragon } );

function agregarDragon( geometria )
{
    geometria.materials[0][0].shading = THREE.FlatShading;
    geometria.materials[0][0].morphTargets = true;

    var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial();

    modeloDragon = new THREE.Mesh( geometria, material );
    modeloDragon.scale.set(50,50,50); 
    escena.add( modeloDragon );
}
```

some Dragon.js:

```js
{

"metadata" :
{
    "formatVersion" : 3,
    "sourceFile"    : "Dragon.obj",
    "generatedBy"   : "OBJConverter",
    "vertices"      : 3143,
    "faces"         : 11130,
    "normals"       : 10066,
    "colors"        : 0,
    "uvs"           : 1172,
    "materials"     : 3
},

"scale" : 1.000000,

"materials": [      {
    "DbgColor" : 15658734,
    "DbgIndex" : 0,
    "DbgName" : "Material__35"
    },

    {
    "DbgColor" : 15597568,
    "DbgIndex" : 1,
    "DbgName" : "Material__47"
    },

    {
    "DbgColor" : 60928,
    "DbgIndex" : 2,
    "DbgName" : "Material__83"
    }],

"vertices": [-0.696100,0.260000,0.408700,....]
.
.
}
```

when I try to load with chrome  generates the following error

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

and emphasizes the line

```js
"metadata" :
```

and Minefield with firebug:

```
 invalid label: Dragon.js(line 3, col 4 )
 "metadata" :
```

why this error is generated?

how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, two things

1. was working with version 47, and the change for the 49
2. Change the way you load the model

```js
loader.load( '/modelos/modelos3D/Dragon.js',function( geometria )
{
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometria, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial( {overdraw:true}  ));
        escena.add( mesh );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe caused by semicolon insertion. Try this

```
  "metadata" : {
   //the rest of your json
   }
```